Is it possible to test whether a destination with a given name is referenced or not?
In a class I'm working on, I create a command that lets the user specify the credit of a figure. When a figure is credited, automatic hyperlinks between the figure and the credit (in a list of credits) is automatically created. It works well except that, for figures whom credits are not specified, warnings of the form “warning  (pdf backend): unreferenced destination with name ⟨destination name⟩” are emitted.
Hence, I'd like to create a command with the following logic:
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
  % Pseudo-code (start)
  If ⟨destination⟩ with ⟨name⟩ is referenced
  Then
  % Pseudo-code (end)
    \hyperlink{⟨name⟩}{#1}
  % Pseudo-code (start)
  Else
  % Pseudo-code (end)
    #1
  % Pseudo-code (start)
  Endif
  % Pseudo-code (end)
}

Is it possible to test whether a destination with a given name is referenced?

Use labels, then you can test if the label name exists: \ifcsname r@name\endcsname\hyperref[name]{xxx}\fi

@UlrikeFischer Is it possible to do something similar for targets defined with \MakeLinkTarget*?

Simply put a label behind the target, hyperref will pick up this name.
